# Lines skipped when writing to csv in ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, sinatra

I'm writing a small application that takes data from an uploaded csv file, parses each line and then rearranges the data in a new csv file, which is then downloaded.

Here is the code that creates the new csv file and downloads it:

```
CSV.open("template.csv", "w") do |csv|


  @formatted_lines.each do |line|

    csv << line
  end


  # Download CSV
  send_file("template.csv", :disposition => 'attachment', :filename => File.basename("template.csv"))

end
```

I end up with a csv file with 270 lines, even though the @formatted_lines array has 280 lines/arrays in it. There is nothing wrong with the data in the original csv file that would cause an error when it is parsed. Why would it cut off the last 10 lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not actually closing the file before trying to send it, it's possible that the last ten lines are just buffered and haven't been written to disk. Try doing the `send_file` after the `CSV.open` block.

Comment: I forgot to mark this as correct two weeks ago. You were exactly right, thanks!